# C++ Visual Studio interprets the class method as static

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio interprets the class method as static but they are not. I have 110 Errors when i build below code.

Errors: [Foto with errors 1.](http://scr.hu/984a/59ku9) , [Foto with errors 2.](http://scr.hu/984a/nh34e)

It may wrong declares these methods?

```
//header    
class Player {
    public:
        Player(int x, int y) {
            PlayerX = x;
            PlayerY = y;
        };
        void doAction(int input, Mapa *mapa);
        int getDirection();
        Vector2 getPosition();

        int 

PlayerX, PlayerY, direction;

        void turn(int dir);
        void move(int move, Vector2 mapSize, Mapa *mapa);
        Vector2 getCordInFrontOfCharacter();
        Vector2 getCordBehindCharacter();
    };
```

and cpp file:

```
#include "Vector2.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include "Mapa.h"

using namespace std;


int PlayerX = 0, PlayerY = 0;
int direction = 0;


void Player::doAction(int input, Mapa *mapa) {
    if (input == (char)72)
        this->move(1, *mapa->mapSize, mapa);
    else if (input == (char)80)
        this->move(-1, *mapa->mapSize, mapa);
    if (input == (char)75)
        this->turn(-1);
    else if (input == (char)77)
        this->turn(1);
}

void Player::turn(int dir) {
    if (dir < 0)
        dir = 2 - dir;
    direction = (direction + dir) % 4;
}

void Player::move(int move, Vector2 mapSize, Mapa *mapa) {

    if (
        move = 1 
        && getCordInFrontOfCharacter().y - 1 >= 0
        && getCordInFrontOfCharacter().x - 1 >= 0
        && getCordInFrontOfCharacter().y - 1 < mapSize.y
        && getCordInFrontOfCharacter().x - 1 < mapSize.x
        && mapa->_Mapa[getCordInFrontOfCharacter().y - 1][getCordInFrontOfCharacter().x - 1] == '0') {

        if (this->direction == 0)
            this->PlayerY -= move;
        else if (this->direction == 2)
            this->PlayerY += move;
        else if (this->direction == 1)
            this->PlayerX += move;
        else if (this->direction == 3)
            this->PlayerX -= move;

        if (this->PlayerY < 1)
            this->PlayerY = 1;
        if (this->PlayerX < 1)
            this->PlayerX = 1;
        if (this->PlayerY > mapSize.y)
            this->PlayerY = mapSize.y;
        if (this->PlayerX > mapSize.x)
            this->PlayerX = mapSize.x;
    }
    else if (   
        move = 1 
        && this->getCordBehindCharacter().y - 1 >= 0
        && this->getCordBehindCharacter().x - 1 >= 0
        && this->getCordBehindCharacter().y - 1 < mapSize.y
        && this->getCordBehindCharacter().x - 1 < mapSize.x
        && mapa->_Mapa[this->getCordBehindCharacter().y - 1][this->getCordBehindCharacter().x - 1] == '0') {

        if (this->direction == 0)
            this->PlayerY -= move;
        else if (this->direction == 2)
            this->PlayerY += move;
        else if (this->direction == 1)
            this->PlayerX += move;
        else if (this->direction == 3)
            this->PlayerX -= move;

        if (this->PlayerY < 1)
            this->PlayerY = 1;
        if (this->PlayerX < 1)
            this->PlayerX = 1;
        if (this->PlayerY > mapSize.y)
            this->PlayerY = mapSize.y;
        if (this->PlayerX > mapSize.x)
            this->PlayerX = mapSize.x;
    }
}

int Player::getDirection() {
    return this->direction;
}

Vector2 Player::getPosition() {
    return Vector2(this->PlayerX, this->PlayerY);
}

Vector2 Player::getCordInFrontOfCharacter() {
    if (this->direction == 2)
        return Vector2(this->PlayerX, this->PlayerY + 1);
    else if (this->direction == 0)
        return Vector2(this->PlayerX, this->PlayerY - 1);
    else if (this->direction == 3)
        return Vector2(this->PlayerX - 1, this->PlayerY);
    else if (this->direction == 1)
        return Vector2(this->PlayerX + 1, this->PlayerY);
    return Vector2(0, 0);
}

Vector2 Player::getCordBehindCharacter() {
    if (direction == 2)
        return Vector2(this->PlayerX, this->PlayerY - 1);
    else if (this->direction == 0)
        return Vector2(this->PlayerX, this->PlayerY + 1);
    else if (this->direction == 3)
        return Vector2(this->PlayerX + 1, this->PlayerY);
    else if (this->direction == 1)
        return Vector2(this->PlayerX - 1, this->PlayerY);
    return Vector2(0, 0);
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: I don't know about the methods (please make a [mcve]) but you're trying to initialize non-static data members like they were static. You also have a stray semicolon after the constructor.

Comment: Thank You James for your speedy reply.  In cpp file i initialize non-static methods with "::". It is the right operator?

Comment: Assuming that you're intention was to initialize data members, this is wrong: `int PlayerX = 0, PlayerY = 0; int direction = 0;` This is wrong, too: `move = 1 `

Comment: @maciej You can't "initialize" a method. You can initialize a _member_ by setting its value in the constructor (or in certain situations in the class definition). Initializing them outside of the class doesn't make sense because they need to be set everytime an instance is created.

Comment: @Maciej I cannot see anything wrong with your implementation. The only thing I can imagine that the compiler gets confused about the parameter name and function name are the same. Try something like. `move_` as parameter name.

Comment: `int PlayerX = 0, PlayerY = 0;int direction = 0;` in the cpp, what is this supposed to mean? If those members are not  static id does not make sense to assign them a value without an object. However, I dont think this is causing your error, because its just some globals unrelated to the class.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks a lot! This caused all this 110 errors. :)

Comment: @Maciej Well, that was a wild guess. I wrote it as an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Visual Studio compilater apparently gets confused at this function signature

```
 void Player::move(int move, Vector2 mapSize, Mapa *mapa)
```

where the same name is used for a parameter and the function itself.
Change that to make them distinct:

```
 void Player::move(int move_, Vector2 mapSize, Mapa *mapa) 
                        // ^
```

Answer (score 0):

> In cpp file i initialize non-static methods with "::"

It's pretty much impossible to initialize method in c++. I you meant class members, well, then that's wrong.

If you have non-static member, you can't do that:

```
int foo::member = 0; // error, member is non-static
```

Every foo object has it's own `int member`, so it's not shared between them. You must set it for every object in constructor (maybe default values are what you are looking for):

```
foo::foo (int _mem = 0, ... ) : member(_mem) {...}
```

Comment: Yes, that was second reason of my mistakes. Thanks for help. Main reason was the same name of parameter and method.